# Quotation Mark punctuation on thoughts

Tags: phrases, punctuation, commas, periods

I was writing a review on Goodreads and a question emerged after these sentences.

*When I was just a wee little boy I would finish this book thinking **"Wow. Wonderland Rocks."** Today I finished this book with the thought **"I miss being a child able to enjoy utter nonsense."***

So, where should I place the periods ending the quotations (inside or outside)? Should I use commas before those quotations?

Comment: There's plenty of style issues round the web. Seek one you like most and keep to it.

Comment: @SovereignSun - There's more to it than that. (For example, I'd avoid using a US style guide in the UK, especially in matters where they customarily disagree.)

Comment: The fact it is thoughts has no effect on the usual style rules for placing punctuation around quote marks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out, punctuation style may vary according to dialect.

The most conventional way of punctuating these sentences in American English is as follows.

> When I was just a wee little boy, I would finish this book, thinking, "Wow. Wonderland Rocks."
>
> Today I finished this book with the thought, "I miss being a child able to enjoy utter nonsense."

British English follows a slightly different style, and is arguably more sensible:

> When I was just a wee little boy, I would finish this book, thinking, 'Wow. Wonderland Rocks'.
>
> Today I finished this book with the thought, 'I miss being a child able to enjoy utter nonsense'.

You'll notice the British style puts periods and commas outside (not inside) of single-quotes (not double-quotes). (Source: http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/british-versus-american-style.html)

Also, notice there are a few more commas in these sentences than you had used, including after ***thinking*** and ***thought***.

Finally, notice the comma after ***book*** in the first sentence. I added the comma, because without it the sentence technically means the book was thinking. It's a subtle point, but good to know if you want to master written English.

Since these are internal thoughts (called **indirect internal dialogue**), you can also use italics instead of quotes. I prefer to use this style myself:

> When I was just a wee little boy, I would finish this book, thinking, *Wow. Wonderland Rocks.*
>
> Today I finished this book with the thought, *I miss being a child able to enjoy utter nonsense.*

Again, the commas are important, as they are in this example:

> *I miss being a child*, he thought, *able to enjoy utter nonsense.*

(Source: http://data.grammarbook.com/blog/quotation-marks/internal-dialogue-italics-or-quotes/)